# Magento Patch issue SUPEE-5344

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

Using terminal in mac, I'm trying to apply patch SUPEE-5344. I've uploaded the patch to the magento root directory, I run the sh script and  I'm receiving this:

```
    Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
    ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

    can't find file to patch at input line 5
    Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

The text leading up to this was:

    diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
    index bd00181..6a5281c 100644
    --- app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
    +++ app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php

    File to patch: 
    Skip this patch? [y] 
    Skipping patch.
    3 out of 3 hunks ignored
    can't find file to patch at input line 46
    Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

   The text leading up to this was:

    diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
    index 6513db9..31eb6d6 100644
    --- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
    +++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php

    File to patch: 
    Skip this patch? [y] 
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored
    can't find file to patch at input line 91
    Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

The text leading up to this was:

    diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
    index c30d273..36542f9 100644
    --- app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
    +++ app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php

    File to patch: 
    Skip this patch? [y] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    can't find file to patch at input line 104
    Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

The text leading up to this was:

    diff --git app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
    index e6cb947..36142ac 100644
    --- app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
    +++ app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php

    File to patch: 
    Skip this patch? [y] 
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored
    can't find file to patch at input line 126
    Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

The text leading up to this was:

    diff --git lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
    index 2226331..d1c6942 100644
    --- lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
    +++ lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

    File to patch: 
    Skip this patch? [y] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

---

Help ASAP please.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? Did you download the correct patch for your Magento version? Did you apply any other patches before?

Comment: were you in the magento root directory while executing the patch? does `ls app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php` list the Observer.php file?

Answer (score 3):

If for *all files* you see the message "can't find file to patch at input line X", you are probably either

1. running the patch script in the wrong place: move it to the Magento root directory, `cd` into it and run the script
2. not having the right permissions. Try running the script as another user that has access to the Magento source files or use `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

You can find the patches in following the URL to install without SSH
https://www.milople.com/blogs/ecommerce/applying-magento-security-patch.html